# does kotlin has by name parameter support?

Tags: kotlin

Scala has by name parameter support and its usage looks like this, is it possible to achieve this in kotlin?

```
  def invoke(block: => Boolean) = block

  // usage
  var exposure = 0
  invoke(exposure == 1)
```

I have the following method in kotlin:

```
fun waitFor(condition: () -> Boolean) = condition()

// usage
var exposure = 0
waitFor { exposure == 1 }

waitFor(exposure == 1) // I want its usage to look like this, but it does not compile
```

`waitFor` is a part of our custom DSL which takes a block and it needs to evaluate it every time it gets called.

Comment: "our custom DSL which takes a block" `exposure == 1` is not a block. Don't fight the language just because you're used to something from another lanuage. Use `waitFor { exposure == 1 }`

Comment: What do you mean by fight language? This is a genuine question I have asked and was wondering if this is possible with some other language features like operator overloading, invoke or lambda with a receiver. 
I am not saying why this is not supported. And I am not after this syntax because I have used it in another language, as I said this is part of our custom DSL and DSL would look nice if I am able to write it as mentioned in the post with some workarounds if possible.

Comment: Tim probably meant that call by name is mostly against the pragmatism of explicitness of the Kotlin language. By name is confusing and I'd argue paradoxically less readable. It seems to me like Scala is constantly at war with the `{` block, something which I can not get behind..

Comment: I completely agree that by name is confusing and I personally do not prefer it. But I was stuck with a use case where I have a `loop` dsl which looks like below
`loop { waitFor { x == 1 } ... stopWhen(y == 5) }` . I wanted `waitFor` and `stopWhen` look similar syntactically. x is a `var` here and can be mutated from other coroutine/thread hence need to be evaluated every fixed poll interval and need to be function.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin does not support call by name, but you can emulate this feature (with limitations) using delegated properties and these can be used locally too.

First consider Kotlin's lazy value.
Kotlin's lazy is implemented through delegated properties. Lazy value is evaluated at the time it is first accessed and can be used as call by name in case you only need to evaluate once.

```
val exposure by lazy { 0 }
waitFor(exposure == 1)
```

You can implement custom delegated property that will give you almost the semantics of call by name

```
fun <T> callByName(block: () -> T) = object: ReadOnlyProperty<Any?, T> {
   override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = block()
}
```

Variable or property defined like this will evaluate using the supplied block on every access, sort of lazily. This is not the same as by name as the variable still evaluates when the block its scoped in evaluates, which here happens before the call of the method `waitFor`.

```
val exposure by callByName { UUID.randomUUID() }
val alwaysFalse = exposure == exposure
waitFor(exposure == 1)
```

This can be useful in simple cases, but not in cases where you want the whole block to be called by name.